# Dynamic formulas for match with several criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a small table in C3:D11. The formula in G3 is `=UNIQUE(C3:C11)`, which is dynamic array. I manually list several numbers in H3:K3.

Then I would like to fill in the table H3:K8. Let's take H3 for example. If in the raw table, there exists a row whose first element is `A` and second element is `1`, then H3 is TRUE. The formula `=NOT(ISERROR(XMATCH(1,($G3=$C$3:$C$11)*(H$2=$D$3:$D$11),FALSE)))` works fine (although i'm not sure if it is the best). Then we could copy paste the formula to the whole table.

[image]

However, the problem of the above table is that it is not dynamic; it does not spill. I'm thinking how to write a dynamic formula that could spill. I tried in H3 `=NOT(ISERROR(XMATCH(1,($G3#=$C$3:$C$11)*(H$2=$D$3:$D$11),FALSE)))`. It did work for H3, but it did not spill to the rest of Column H.

Does anyone know how to write dynamic formulas to achieve this match with multiple criteria?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(G3#&H2:K2,C3:C11&D3:D11,0))
```

**The To-One-up-Tom-Solution** ;-)

If you wanted the whole table created by the formula dynamically, you could do:

```
=LET( array, C3:D11,
       ltrs, INDEX(array,,1), nmbrs, INDEX(array,,2),
       uLtrs, UNIQUE(ltrs), lSeq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(uLtrs)+1,,0),
       uNmbrs, UNIQUE(nmbrs), nSeq, SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(uNmbrs)+1,0),
       bools, ISNUMBER(MATCH(uLtrs&TRANSPOSE(uNmbrs),ltrs&nmbrs,0)),
       yNotCreateTheWholeTableTom, IF((lSeq=0)*(nSeq=0),"table",
                IF(lSeq=0,INDEX(TRANSPOSE(uNmbrs),1,nSeq),
                    IF(nSeq=0,INDEX(uLtrs,lSeq,),INDEX(bools,lSeq,nSeq)) ) ),
       yNotCreateTheWholeTableTom )
```

Where C3:D11 is the input to a LET formula that goes into **array**. All other variable names are there to make the process clear or for comedic purposes.

Comment: Sure, @SoftTimur - it is an interesting problem - may encounter it again.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would use Countifs, although Match or Xmatch should be possible:

```
=COUNTIFS(C3:C100,UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(C3:C100,C3:C100<>""))),D3:D100,TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(D3:D100,C3:C100<>"")))))>0
```

in H3.

I think it would be awkward to try and do the whole thing with one big formula, so I would use a separate formula for the columns headers and row headers:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(D3:D100,C3:C100<>""))))
```

and

```
=UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(C3:C100,C3:C100<>"")))
```

[image]

Of course (having looked at @Mark Fitzpatrick's answer!) I could just have put

```
=COUNTIFS(C3:C100,G3#,D3:D100,H2#)>0
```

for the first formula.

Comment: Thanks Tom - you made me laugh. OK, so I responded in kind. May the best formula win.