# Dynamic formulas for match with several criteria (one by one)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Previously, I posted a question about [Dynamic formulas for match with several criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152835/dynamic-formulas-for-match-with-several-criteria). The idea of the answer is to use `&` to combine columns.

But I would prefer a solution where we really check criteria in several columns one by one. Here is an example:

[image]

The raw data is in B3:C8. F2 is `=UNIQUE(RIGHT(B3:B8,LEN(B3:B8)-5))`, so it dynamically extracts all the people. G1:I1 is manually entered. By using `=ISNUMBER(XMATCH(1,("who: "&$F2=$B$3:$B$8)*(G$1=$C$3:$C$8),0,))` in G2 and copying it to G2:I4, we could well fill in the table and find if a person has a fruit. So that's good.

I would like to make this formula dynamic. I tried `=ISNUMBER(XMATCH(1,("who: "&$F2#=$B$3:$B$8)*(G$1=$C$3:$C$8),0,))` in G2, but it did not spill (anyone knows why?).

So does anyone have a dynamic solution (without lambda function if possible), whose structure contains `("who: "&$F2=$B$3:$B$8)*(G$1=$C$3:$C$8)`? I prefer this structure to `&` because we could really write any expression for criteria one by one.

Comment: I lied, countifs will do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"=*"&F2#,C:C,"="&G1#)>0
```

[image]

---

Or you can use:

```
=ISNUMBER(XMATCH("*"&F2#&G1#,B:B&C:C,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks... it is dynamic. But what COUNTIFS bothers me is that the criteria expression is "partial". For example, if we have a VBA function `checkCell(F2#)` that returns a boolean, we could not really put it into a criteria.

Comment: That is correct, but we have to use the ability for countifs to take arrays as criteria.  Other array formulas, outside LAMBDA will only iterate one way.  You can do `B2=F2#` or `B:B=F2` but you cannot do `B:B=F2#` that is a nested loop situation.  You could do a helper column that is a concatenation of the lookup columns then XLOOKUP could possibly work.